# how to convert a float to a decimal so i can display it in a numeric up down

Tags: c#, winforms, floating-point, decimal, converters

this is currently my code

```
        byte[] bytes = { 0x42, 0x1c, 00, 00 };
        float flt = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

now I know the floating point's decimal value is 39.0 but no matter what I try or do whether it be convert.todecimal or just casting it. It displays as 0 I don't know why it does this but I could really use help here. I don't care about precision so you don't have to worry about that.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

revert the order of the byte array, then it works

```
byte[] bytes = { 00, 00, 0x1c, 0x42};
```